# What's the correct way to change name of form element in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, rename, element

I'm using Visual Studio, I have generated a form & added a button but unfortunately I have named **btn_test1** instead of **Btn_test1** (small vs large beginning letter) & double clicked the button to generate the click function and visual Studio happily generated the: **btn_test1_Click()** function & then complained that the function didn't start with a capital letter.

I thought: "Ok, no problem", went back & renamed the button to **Btn_test1** & changed the click function to **Btn_test1_Click()** and now instead Visual Studio gives me an error that **btn_test1_Click()** is missing.

**My question is:** What is the proper procedure I should have used in this case?

If you don't want to write a long answer but have a link to some documentation it's fine too.

Comment: Right clicking and choosing rename may be useful, since it applies the rename to all the uses of the variable/property/method/etc

Comment: Let me see if I understood: You renamed the button AND the clicked delegate reference to `Btn_test1` and `Btn_test1_Click` respectively and you're getting an error saying `btn_test1_clicked` is missing?

Comment: Trick: F2 (Refactoring in Visual Studio Code). Not sure if it can be aplied in this specific instance, but I have resently learned about Visual Studio Codes's refactor function, I know it works for variable names, but it might also work on function names too. §1: Select the name. §2: Press F2. §3: Type the new name + Enter. §4: Double check so it didn't mess up something. https://medium.com/@i_AnkurBiswas/pro-tips-for-visual-studio-code-to-be-productive-in-2018-d5252e914561#18e9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, **there is no need for a capital letter at the beginning** of a name property, I'm also using VS 2017. I'll give some screenshots how to rename a function.

**Step 1**: Click on the **events** of the button in the properties panel as shown in the following image
[image]

**Step 2**: Find click event, and Delete the text

[image]

[image]

**Step 3**: Go to Properties in the properties panel

[image]

**Step 4**: Select the Name property of the button.

[image]

**Step 5**: Rename it as you like,

[image]

**Step 6**: **Double click the button on the designer**, it will automatically create a function with the new name.

As for the **naming convention**, use as I mentioned in the image.

for example, a button to send something can be named as ***btnSend***. 
*btn* -> stands for button. *Send* -> represents the name.

---

**Note**:

After you have successfully renamed and generated the new click event code. The old click event code will just be there. If you need the content of the old event copy it to the new click event code.

Also, if you still stuck with some error states that the old function is missing. Read the Designer.cs file carefully and delete all lines associated with the old function name.

Comment: I tried it, and it corectly generates a new function with the right name, but VS still complains that the old function have a lower case letter, and if I remove that function then I get an error instead, that the function is missing. However I learned about the lightning icon from this & the screenshots are really helpful. However St. Pat's solution of Right Click & rename worked & removed the errors.

Comment: ...But apparently the Right click & rename don't change the (name) in the Designer, which is really strange.

Comment: so the function name is stuck somewhere in the form.Designer.cs. Locate the file and search the old function name. And delete all lines with the old function name.

Comment: ...And the right click & rename says it will change the name in 2 files, is there a way to see which 2 files is changed?

Comment: read the designer.cs file for the particular form, you can understand it easily

Comment: This is really strange, in the **Form1.cs** the function is called **Btn...()** (I shorten the name here), in the **Form1.Designer.cs** it's called **btn...** and in the **Form1.cs [Design]** it's called **btn...**. But as I understand it **Btn...** & **btn...** should be 2 completely different names & I should have compilation errors or something? I don't even have a warning.

Comment: Delete the Btn...() lines completely. Clean the Solution and build it

Comment: Ok, that worked, but only if I did it in the right order, otherwise the **Form1.cs [Design]** completely crashes. **To future readers:** #1 use the right click & rename. #2 if that fails, generate the new correctly named function **FIRST** then delete the old one, then go into the previously mentioned 3 files and make sure the right name is in all files, VS might try to reset the name some times, but keep renaming the things until it works.

Answer (score 1):

Form1.cs [Design] crashes when you try to delete the event that is bound with button.

While making such changes -

1. Go to Button properties and remove the function name from click event.
2. Change the Button name
3. Again go to click event and do double click it (VS will generate click event for you)
4. Now you can delete the previous click event from your code without making your Form1.cs(design) crash.